# Inserting a not floating image

Tags: graphics, floats, multicol

I need to add a picture to to a latex document and apply `multicol` environments to it so it may not float. If I just use `\includegraphics` it can be used with `multicol` but I cannot use a caption for it. If I put `\begin{figure}` and `\end{fingure}` around `\includegraphics` it cannot be used in `minipage` and `multicol` space.

How can I add a not floating figure with a caption?

Comment: `\captionof{figure}{Your caption}` works even without floating/figure environment You need the `caption` package

Comment: What's your question?  This answer might help if it's to do with putting a float where you want it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8633/28808

Comment: @ChristianHupfer where should I add it. How I connect it to a figure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use`\captionof{figure}{your normal caption}` text for a non-floating graphics (or for a table: `\captionof{table}{caption text}`)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \blindtext
  \begin{center}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{bild_erwin_schroedinger}
  \captionof{figure}{Erwin}
  \end{center}
\blindtext
  \begin{center}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{a_1.jpg}
  \captionof{figure}{A famous duck}
  \end{center}
  \blindtext
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there anywhere to add a label to the picture?

Comment: @user62181: Of course, just say `\label{foo}` after `\captionof{...}{...}` -- it works the usual way!