# Add left indent/margin to figure

Tags: floats

[image]

Is there a way to make a figure placement centering relative to parent indent?

```
\begin{figure}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Then don't use a floating environment...?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. As the old saying goes, "the devil is in the details". Unless you provide some detailed information about your document setup and about the layout of section-level and subsection-level headers, it's not likely anyone will be able to provide you specific and actionable suggestions for how you might go about achieving your formatting objective.

Comment: thanks for the reply,
Sorry i kinda new to latex, what i hope to achive is simply adding a left margin to the figure and the figure caption. 

For example add 1cm left margin to figure
(so the caption stay centered relative to the figure)

Comment: if you include an image then it will follow the current indentation, but the only purpose of the `figure` evironment is to mark it as not part of the document flow but an insert that can float, so it is reset  to document default settings

Comment: Ah i see, 
i just try it out and without "figure" the image seems to perfectly align with what I wanted. but if I don't use figure" then I can't use captions, is it possible to use "caption" without using "figure"? (and i also need to use figure automatic numbering....)

Comment: With `\captionof{figure}{ <caption text> }` defined in the `caption` and `capt-of` packages.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your reply and help. I just found the solutions to my problem is simply not using figure as placeholder instead use \captionof

ref
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275224/inserting-a-not-floating-image
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452887/remove-figures-but-keep-references-to-image